# Javascript:: From innerHTML to appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, appendchild

So.. I understand that innerHTML is very buggy (although in my code it's working perfectly) but I prefer to covert my code from innerHTML to appendChild.

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qrLsjjdg/

Here is my code (which is working perfectly) :

```
<style>
#gangina
{
    clear:both;
    float:left
}
</style>

<div id=myBox>
    <div id=hezi></div>
    <a href="#" id=gangina>attach another file</a>
</div>

<script>
window.onload=appendMore;
document.getElementById("gangina").addEventListener("click",appendMore);

function appendMore()
{
    hezi.innerHTML+="<div id=ganginaUploadBox style='clear:both;float:left'><progress id=hezi></progress><button id=yehezkel>Upload</button></div>";
}
</script>
```

BUT... How do I convert it all to appendChild?

Comment: `So.. I understand that innerHTML is very buggy` How that?

Comment: That's what they say...

Answer (score 1):

The corretct thing to do is to create some elements and append them to the DOM, something like this:

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.style="clear:both;float:left";
div.id="ganginaUploadBox";
p = document.createElement("progress");
p.id="heziProgress";
b = document.createElement("button");
b.id="yehezkel";
div.appendChild(p);
div.appendChild(b);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrLsjjdg/1/

PS: watch out for the duplicated IDs